# Loading contents of files into a NextJs app at runtime as env vars

Tags: reactjs, azure, kubernetes, next.js, environment-variables

I'm trying to load the contents of files in a specific folder as env vars accessible at process.env.SomethingHere at runtime not build time as those files don't exist at build time yet (if process.env is the right place to load those secrets, more about that in the end). I managed to write the code to read the files and create a key-value object/dictionary from them, but not sure where is the best spot in the app lifecycle to add this so it's available for both server-side middleware and client-side frontend

```
function readFiles(dir) {
  var vars = {};
  if(!fs.existsSync(dir))
  {
    console.log("failed to load files in directory: " + dir);
    return vars;
  }

  // read directory
  let fileNames = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  if (!fileNames) {
    console.log("failed to load files in directory: " + dir);
    return vars;
  }
    
  fileNames.forEach((filename, index) => {
    // get current file name
    const name = path.parse(filename).name;
    // get current file path
    const filepath = path.resolve(dir, filename);

    // get information about the file
    let stat = fs.statSync(filepath);

    if (!stat) {
      console.log("failed to load file stats: " + name);
      return;
    }

    // check if the current path is a file or a folder
    const isFile = stat.isFile();

    // exclude folders
    if (isFile) {
      let data = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
      if (!data) {
        console.log("failed to load file: " + name);
        return;
      }
      let content = data.toString('utf8', 0, data.length);
      // callback, do something with the file
      vars[name] = content;
    }
  });

  return vars;
}
```

Some background:

I'm using Azure keyvault for storing secrets and have a Kubernetes cluster with a frontend and a backend pod.

In the backend pod I was able to mount the secrets using CSI driver fetch the values at app startup and load that into the python os.environ. I'm trying to achieve the same for the frontend pod, the mounting is successful, but I haven't been able to place my code in the right spot to load the secrets into process.env if this is even the right place to add them.

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT solved the issue eventually, here is the answer:

In a Next.js application, the server-side entry point is the server.js file located in the root directory of the project. By default, this file exports the createServer function, which is used to create the Express server that handles server-side rendering of the application.

You can add your code to load the environment variables in this file by importing the readFiles function and using the Object.assign() method to merge the key-value object with the existing process.env object, like this:

**env.js**

```
function readFiles(dir) {
  // existing code here
}
module.exports = readFiles;
```

**server.js** in the root directory of the project

```
const readFiles = require('./env');
const dir = './dir_name'
const envVars = readFiles(dir);
Object.assign(process.env, envVars);

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000

const {createServer} = require('next');
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(handle).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
  });
});
```